# Searching Window Spread in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity

The super + w shortcut which "window spreads" will not let me search through windows. I tried messing with ccsm but still cannot figure out what is wrong.

Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

The filter by window option is available through the plugin "Scale Window Title Filter".

You'll need to install the extra package:

[compiz-plugins-extra](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins-extra)

[image: Install compiz-plugins-extra]

[image: pic]

Once done you'll be able to filter your windows by typing part of the window title:

[image]